# Smallest distance between matrix and vector

Tags: octave

I have a matrix with dimension NxM and one vector with length M. I need the smallest distance of all the distances between each row of the matrix and the single vector.

My approach was to create a second matrix using repmat and then calculate the distances between each row, but I am only getting the total distance:

```
matrix2 = repmat(vector, N, 1);
norm(matrix1 - matrix2, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show this with an example:

```
m = rand (5, 2);  # Your matrix with reference points
v = rand (1, 2);  # Your vector

tmp = bsxfun(@minus, m, v);
d = hypot (tmp(:,1), tmp(:,2)); # Difference between v and all rows in m

# Find samllest distance
[dmin, ix] = min (d)

# visualize it
scatter (m(:,1), m(:,2), 8, "red");
hold on
plot([v(1), m(ix, 1)], [v(2), m(ix, 2)], "-*")
hold off

print ("out.png")
```

The red bubbles are points in m (2D case) and the "*" one is v. A blue line connects v with the one from m, which ist nearest to.

[image: Smallest distance]

Answer (score 1):

I think on `octave`, you can use `automatic broadcasting` to get the distances without `repmat-ing` or using `norm` like so -

```
dist = sum((matrix1 - vector).^2,2)
```

---

On `MATLAB`, you can avoid `repmat` with `bsxfun` like this -

```
dist = sum(bsxfun(@minus,matrix1,vector).^2,2)
```

---

And, if you still like to continue with `repmat`, you can get the distances like so -

```
matrix2 = repmat(vector, N, 1);
dist = sum((matrix1 - matrix2).^2,2)
```

---

Finally, to get the smallest distance and the corresponding row index, you can use `min` -

```
[smallest_dist,minrow_ind] = min(dist)
```